# Plotly: How to embed a fully interactive Plotly figure in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, vba, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to embed an interactive plotly (or bokeh) plot into excel.

To do this I've tried the following three things:

1. embed a Microsoft Web Browser UserForm into excel, following:

> [How do I embed a browser in an Excel VBA form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501213/how-do-i-embed-a-browser-in-an-excel-vba-form)

This works and enables both online and offline html to be loaded

2. creating a plotly html

'''

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go


x = [0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0]
y = [i**2 for i in x]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=x, mode='markers', name="y=x", marker=dict(color='royalblue', size=8)))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, name="y=x^2", line=dict(width=3)))

plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='C:/Users/.../pythonProject/test1.html')
```

3. repointing the webbrowser object in excel using `.Navigate` to the local  plotly.html. Banner pops up with

*".... restricted this file from showing active content that could access your computer"*

clicking on the banner, I run into this error:

[image]

The same HTML can be opened in a browser.

Is there any way to show interactive plots in excel?

Comment: Correct, the excel webbrowser will open html, but  fails when opening the plotly created "test1.html". However, "test1.html" can be opened in a browser (chrome, IE etc). In IE one needs to enable ActiveX controls, but otherwise it works fine.

Comment: The problem occurs when the HTML trying to use the JavaScript https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.2.3.min.js

Comment: You have to enable Macros (and JS) in Microsoft Excel!

Comment: Can you share the plotly html file? I would like to make some tests.

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you're looking for but you could try [Microsoft Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/), load in your Excel data, and then add your custom Plotly code.

Comment: Is there a way we can exactly replicate your problem? I.e. do we need the html file for example? Also, what happens in step 3 after you click `yes` to running scripts?

Comment: @dusiod https://www.wikihow.com/Enable-JavaScript-in-Internet-Explorer Please try this

Comment: @QHarr to replicate the HTML one needs to run the code in step 2 "creating a plotly html" above, this will save down the HTML to a defined location. Next is to load into excel, at which point the error above appears, clicking "yes" gives a second error "Plotly is undefined"

Comment: So what was wrong with letting the user use plotly in a browser?

Comment: @dusiod I know i was late to give an answer but still managed to give you an easy working and fully interactive solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/65678371/10849457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have managed to bring the interactive plot to excel after a discussion from Microsoft [QnA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/214388/excel-activex-control-microsoft-web-browser-is-not.html?childToView=226296#answer-226296) and [Web Browser Control & Specifying the IE Version](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version)

To insert a Microsoft webpage to excel you have to change the compatibility Flag in the registry editor

*Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\COM Compatibility{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}*

Change the **DWord 0 instead of 400**

Now you can insert the web browser object to excel, Step by step details are [here](https://vikebot.blogspot.com/2021/01/creating-interactive-plotly-in.html)

Edit the HTML File generated from plotly manually by adding a tag for Using the X-UA-Compatible HTML Meta Tag

Originally generated HTML file from plotly looks like this

```
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
<body>
```

Modified HTML with browser compatibility

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
<body>
```

After this, I can able to view the interactive plot in excel also able to do the interactions same as a web browser

[image: Output]

Macro used:

```
Sub Button4_Click()
ActiveSheet.WebBrowser1.Navigate "file:///C:/Users/vignesh.rajendran/Desktop/test5.html"
End Sub
```

Comment: This sounds awesome! But I can't get it to work on my end. I'm getting `Run Time Error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method.` I'm running it on Windows 10 in an `.xlsm` file. Would you care to share some more details about your setup?

Comment: @vestland I am also running in win10 , i have kept my .xlsm file here -> https://gofile.io/d/XaPTSl and python code for generating html here -> https://gofile.io/d/Jvj3nd. if you need anything feel free to ask.

Comment: @Vignesh, This is awesome! Thank you so much, the simplest fixes are sometimes the hardest - I have no idea how you found that but it works! I tried to reactivate / reassign the bounty but the option is not appearing for me.

Comment: @vestlands, i'm running Win10, Office 2019

Comment: @Vignesh Would you please consider describing in detail how you go from an empty Excel file to a working solution? I assume that would be great for other readers as well. And we're not too fond about links to external files and datasets in here either. So a completely working solution (perhaps not the complete html though :-) without links that might not work in a year or so would be great. If you're willing to put in a little extra effort here, I'll see what I can do about that bounty!

Comment: @vestlands, steps are:
1. to get a WebBrowser* object working in excel. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600586/excel-vba-create-an-embedded-webbrowser-and-use-it
2. create plotly HTML, and modify as above
3. repoint the WebBrowser object to the modified plotly HTML (as per Vignesh's example above)
*if the webbrowser doesn't work, google it and you'll need to change an entry in the registry as MS disabled this feature

In either case Vignesh deserves the bounty... ;)

Comment: @vestland I have posted it in a Blog here https://vikebot.blogspot.com/2021/01/creating-interactive-plotly-in.html as its a big story to post here. try it and give me a feedback

Comment: @Vignesh This works pretty great! I will however urge you to make the necessary edits to your SO post to make it reproducible. The only thing you're missing is really the guidance on how to insert the web object and how to make the necessary changes to registry. And you should perhaps also specify that the element you're reassigning values for in the registry is `Compatibility Flags`. If you're willing to do that, the bounty is yours. After all, SO bounty is for SO answers =). In any case, thank you for an insightful answer to a question that a lot of us in here were struggling with!

Comment: @vestland added registry compatibility details and the Blog Link to the post. Hope it was useful to everyone

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @jerlich, Excel blocks javascript. You should try the workaround they linked if you want full interactivity.

If you want at least some degree of controllability or interactivity, try using `xlwings`. With excel buttons, you can still have some communication between Excel and Python (including reading data and sending graphs).

The limitations are:

- Only being able to use data entries and buttons, instead of the default plotly interactive features. Many could be replicated, but it would be more work.
- It will only work on a computer you can set up your python script on (however, it looks like xlwings pro allows you to store your program inside the file)
- It seems you will need to pass plotly graphs by saving and then adding the figure, because directly passing them requires xlwings pro. Direct passing without pro is possible with MatPlotLib.

[Plotly guide to making interactive(ish) graphs](https://plotly.com/python/xlwings/#step-1-connect-to-your-data-in-excel-using-xlwings)

[xlwings docs on MatPlotLib and Plotly graphs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/matplotlib.html)

Comment: I disagree with xlwings recommendation.  Python already has COM interoperability for free.

Answer (score 1):

I like your question! And I'd wish I could give you a better answer, but It seems that the only way you can achieve anything remotely resembling an interactive plotly plot would be to use [pyxll](https://www.pyxll.com/) and follow the steps outlined under [Charts and plotting / Plotly](https://www.pyxll.com/docs/userguide/plotting/plotly.html) including a plot function like this:

```
from pyxll import xl_func, plot
import plotly.express as px

@xl_func
def plotly_plot():
    # Get some sample data from plotly.express
    df = px.data.gapminder()

    # Create a scatter plot figure
    fig = px.scatter(df.query("year==2007"),
                     x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp",
                     size="pop", color="continent",
                     log_x=True, size_max=60)

    # Show the figure in Excel using pyxll.plot
    plot(fig)
```

This will produce the following plot:

[image]

Alas, this will not be a fully interactive plotly plot like we all know and love, since it's also stated on the very same page that:

> The plot that you see in Excel is exported as an image so any
> interactive elements will not be available. To make a semi-interactive
> plot you can add arguments to your function to control how the plot is
> done and when those arguments are changed the plot will be redrawn.

But as far as I know this is as close as you'll get to achieving what you're seeking in your question. If you're not limited to Excel, but somehow limited to the realm of Microsoft, one of the commenters mentioned that you *can* unleash a fully interactive plotly plot in PowerBI. If that is an option, you should take a closer look at [Is it possible to use R Plotly library in R Script Visual of Power BI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368729/is-it-possible-to-use-r-plotly-library-in-r-script-visual-of-power-bi/55022829#55022829). This approach uses `R` though...

Comment: I am puzzled at pyxll, there is COM interoperability already within Python for free. pyxll requires money.

Comment: Fully interactive plot is also working, check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65678371/10849457

Answer (score 0):

Interactive plots require javascript to work. Excel, for security reasons, blocks that javascript. You can put a static image easily into excel.

The challenge of including javascript in excel has been addressed in this question: [How can I use JavaScript within an Excel macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848246/how-can-i-use-javascript-within-an-excel-macro)

Comment: Hi @jerlich, as a disclaimer I'm not (yet) familiar with COM objects, reviewed the linked answer but I do not see how to leverage it for this issue, would you please outline the steps to follow?