# Converting a dataframe of timed tasks to timeline in Excel

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe of tasks at different resources at given times. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'product': ['Prod1', 'Prod1', 'Prod1', 'Prod2', 'Prod2'],
        'resource': ['press', 'coat', 'pack', 'press', 'coat'],
        'start': ['08/02/2024 10:10', '08/02/2024 13:00', '08/02/2024 20:10', '08/02/2024 10:50', '08/02/2024 14:20'],
        'end': ['08/02/2024 10:49', '08/02/2024 14:20', '08/02/2024 22:10', '08/02/2024 11:40', '08/02/2024 16:45'],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
df

  product resource               start                 end
0   Prod1    press 2024-02-08 10:10:00 2024-02-08 10:49:00
1   Prod1     coat 2024-02-08 13:00:00 2024-02-08 14:20:00
2   Prod1     pack 2024-02-08 20:10:00 2024-02-08 22:10:00
3   Prod2    press 2024-02-08 10:50:00 2024-02-08 11:40:00
4   Prod2     coat 2024-02-08 14:20:00 2024-02-08 16:45:00
```

I was able to create a timeline through `plotly` :

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="start", x_end="end", y="resource", color="resource", text="product")
fig.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

I am looking for a way to produce similar timeline but not as an image but in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You first create the figure in exactly the same way you would in any Python script using plotly, and then use PyXLL’s plot function to show it in the Excel workbook.

```
from pyxll import xl_func, plot
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

@xl_func
def display_timeline_in_excel():
    # Define the initial data
    data = {
        'product': ['Prod1', 'Prod1', 'Prod1', 'Prod2', 'Prod2'],
        'resource': ['press', 'coat', 'pack', 'press', 'coat'],
        'start': ['08/02/2024 10:10', '08/02/2024 13:00', '08/02/2024 20:10', '08/02/2024 10:50', '08/02/2024 14:20'],
        'end': ['08/02/2024 10:49', '08/02/2024 14:20', '08/02/2024 22:10', '08/02/2024 11:40', '08/02/2024 16:45'],
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
    df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

    fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="start", x_end="end", y="resource", color="resource", text="product")
    
    
    plot(fig)
```

Know more about [PyXLL](https://www.pyxll.com/docs/userguide/plotting/plotly.html)

[Plotly: How to embed a fully interactive Plotly figure in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65272408/plotly-how-to-embed-a-fully-interactive-plotly-figure-in-excel)

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to create it in Excel not as an image but by actual Excel cells